# "Peel", "pare", and "skin"

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I lately learnt these three words of similar meanings: *peel*, *pare*, and *skin*.

In what case do you use each of them? Could you give me example sentences along with a concise description for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While *peel* and *skin* are both nouns and verbs, *pare* is only a verb, from which I deduce you're talking about these words used as verbs. So:

- **peel** is primarily used for fruits and vegetables (*peel an apple*), as well as clothing  (in the sense of removing: *to peel off one’s pullover*); it can also refer to other coverings on the surface of things
- **skin** is mainly used for persons, animals (*skin the cat*!) and fruits
- **pare** is, in my book, used much less frequently, but is as generic as *skin*

So, as I see it, **skin** is the most generic term, while **peel** refers mostly to fruits and vegetables (you probably wouldn't say you're *peeling the cat*). **pare** is much less used, but as broad as **skin**.

Comment: Some vegetables are certainly pared. Take carrots, for instance. They are neither peeled nor skinned. I'd sooner *skin* fruit (or vegetables) than *peel* them! Some fruits are also pared, depending on how they are eaten. It's certainly not uncommon to pare off rinds of citrus fruits in some parts.

Comment: @Rhodri: Blunder!! I meant to say, "I'd sooner *peel* fruit than *skin* them"!!!! I, for one, never use *skin* in this context. I'd say it's not uncommon to hear *skinned* as an adjective for potatoes, especially. We usually talk of *peeling off skins*, as opposed to *skinning*...

Comment: @Rhodri: I *scrape* carrots and potatoes, too! Also, I'd *skin* potatoes if I boiled them first. Come to think of it, *skin* works better for boiled fruit or vegetables. The term connotes an ease of removal, which boiling usually achieves.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of those verbs is:

- pare: trim something by cutting away its outer edges; cut off the skin of something
- peel: remove the outer covering or skin from a fruit, vegetable, or shrimp
- skin: remove the skin from an animal, a fruit, or vegetable

> Carlo pared his thumbnails with his knife.
>   Peel off the skins and thickly slice the potatoes.
>   He scrambled down from the tree with such haste that he skinned his knees.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Answer (score 2):

[ldoce](http://www.ldoce.com) defines:

- **Peel** [*noun*]: the skin of some fruits and vegetables, especially the thick skin of fruits such as oranges, which you do not eat:

> orange peel

- **Peel** [*verb*]: to remove the skin from fruit or vegetables

> Peel and dice the potatoes.

- **Skin** [*noun*]: the natural outer cover of some fruits and vegetables, the word also has many other meanings.

> banana skins

- **Skin** [*verb*]: to remove the skin from an animal, fruit, or vegetable

> Add the tomatoes, skinned and sliced.

- **Pare** [*verb*]: to cut off the outer layer of something, using a sharp knife

> Pare the rind from the fruit.

It's good to know:

- **rind** [*noun*]: the thick outer skin of some types of fruit, such as oranges

> grated lemon rind

- **zest** [*noun*]: the outer skin of an orange or  lemon , used in cooking

> grated orange zest

Comment: "rind" is also used for the (often inedible, mouldy or otherwise different from the main matter) crust of cheese.

Comment: Thank you! looks like I don't really have to carefully distinguish them when I use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

"pare" has additional meaning and use over "skin" and "peel" in that "skin" and "peel" refer to the removal of a thin outer layer of something (as indicated in the other answers).

"pare" is often used to indicate something was reduced in size or number, but in small increments. It is quite common to hear someone speak of paring something down to its essential elements or paring back the budget for the next fiscal year.

One might think of this as peeling something, then peeling it again, repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you for the complement. Now I can make the last word obvious, which was previously a bit blurry.